# Using long HTML with CSS and JavaScript in PHP generate error in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, phpstorm

I am creating a portal. When the user is logged in, the control goes to `portal.php`. In the portal.php page, I use the following code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link>many link tags are use </link>
    </head>
    <body>
        ------------------------(portal)----------------------------
        -------------too much long html page using css,JavaScript,php,bootstrap-----------------
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP works fine when I use HTML at least, but when I use long HTML in PHP creates an error!

Note: I am using PhpStorm as IDE in which "502 Bad Gateway" error generate!

Comment: Are you sure there is no php code anywhere in that cut off code? Looks to me as server error was generated due error in php code on server side. Check server logs for error description.

Comment: *"502 Bad Gateway"* -- this suggests that you are using PhpStorm's built-in simple web server (it can sometime throw 502 errors for a valid code). I suggest using proper web server (Apache/nginx/IIS/etc) to serve your web pages.

Comment: Just to follow up on a comment above: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/installing-an-amp-package.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother if you share your code chunk then it will be very easy to understand that where you are stucking.

you cando like the example below,

source [How to write html code inside <?php ?>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140270/how-to-write-html-code-inside-php)

```
 <?php
         echo "<table>";
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>Name</td>";
         echo "<td>".$name."</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
         echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

another example you can try

```
<?php 
    $name='your name';
    echo '<table>
       <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
       <tr><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>
    </table>';
?>
```

for javascript

source https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-javascript-from-php

```
 <?php  
    echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">  
         prompt("GeeksForGeeks"); 
         </script>' 
    ; 
    ?>
```

you can visit the below link a similar question has been answered there.

[How to concatenate html stylized table with php and sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598716/how-to-concatenate-html-stylized-table-with-php-and-sql)

Comment: OP is not echoing code in PHP as you can see from the snippet provided. HTML is coming after the closing PHP tag

Comment: Why? sharing code with external links is discouraged on this site for your info.

Comment: do you realize I am not the OP? And the question is pretty much clear and well addressed?

Comment: actually my editor phpstorm generate error for a valid php code